# C# FileLogTraceListener throws exception when closing

Tags: c#, dispose, destructor, finalizer

This is a logging class with a constructor:

```
public QFXLogger(
        int maxFileSize,
        TraceLevel logLevel)
    {
        this.maxFileSize = maxFileSize;
        logSwitch.Level = logLevel;
        //Configure log listener
        traceListener = new FileLogTraceListener();
        traceListener.DiskSpaceExhaustedBehavior = DiskSpaceExhaustedOption.DiscardMessages;
        traceListener.CustomLocation = @".\Log";
        traceListener.BaseFileName = "QFXLog";
        traceListener.AutoFlush = true;
        //Remove all other listeners
        Trace.Listeners.Clear();
        //Add QFX listener
        Trace.Listeners.Add(traceListener);
        //Write header
        WriteSessionHeader();
    }
```

And this is the destrcutor:

```
~QFXLogger()
    {
        WriteSessionFooter();
        traceListener.Close();
    }
```

I just want to write a footer to the underlying stream before the logger gets GC.
Without the destructor everything is fine, but with it I get the following:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file
.
at System.IO.__Error.FileNotOpen()
at System.IO.FileStream.Flush(Boolean flushToDisk)
at System.IO.FileStream.Flush()
at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush()
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener.ReferencedStream.CloseS
tream()
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener.CloseCurrentStream()
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener.Write(String message)
at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.Write(String message)
at System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(String message)
at QFXShell.QFXLogger.WriteSessionFooter()
at QFXShell.QFXLogger.Finalize()
```

It seems to me that the underlying stream was already closed.

How can I suppress this closing(of the underlying stream) or is this another issue?

Comment: @Ramhound WriteSessionFooter does nothing but this: Trace.Write(footerString); The problem is that I would like to write an end statement before the app gets closed.

Comment: This ObjectDisposedException happened to me when calling Stream.Dispose() in my class' IDisposable interface implementation, but stopped happening after I removed call function calls to Stream.Flush().

Comment: Ooops, spoke too soon.  Resolved the issue by ensuring my Dispose(bool isFreeingManagedResources) function was protected virtual, as Kelly Leahy explains on his site.  Previously, I had it as private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalizers (destructors) in c# should not be used in this method. Finalizers are intended *only* to release unmanaged resources. When a finalizer is called, [access to other .net objects is not guaranteed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx) and should only release unmanaged resources that you directly allocated.

> Finalize operations have the following limitations:
>
> - The finalizers of two objects are not guaranteed to run in any specific order, even if one object refers to the other. That is, if Object A has a reference to Object B and both have finalizers, Object B might have already finalized when the finalizer of Object A starts.

What you need to do is implement the [IDisposable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) to properly close your logging file. Some additional information can be found at [Kelly Leahy's IDisposable and Garbage Collection](http://kleahy-technical.blogspot.com/2009/01/idisposable-and-garbage-collection.html).

If you are not in a situation where a disposable class will help (global object, etc.) you can always implement a `Close` method yourself to ensure the file is valid before it is released.

Comment: @Thanks, I'll have a close look.

Answer (score 1):

It is too late for you to close the tracer object in the destructor. In this moment a lot of objects which are not needed any more can be already disposed.
I would propose to implement a IDisposable interface with a public Dispose method and to call this method as soon as you know that you are not going to need this QFXLogger object any more. In this Dispose method, I would check if the tracer object is not NULL, open and then I would call Close on it.
See [Proper use of the IDisposable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface) for more details.